# Can't Get Path Of Photos Taken By ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent

I use Intent and the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTUREto use the camera and take photos, I successfully get the uri of the photo, however when I use this uri to get path, an exception occurred. And when I go to the gallery, I didn't see the photo. I restart the phone and then I see the photo in the gallery. Can anyone tell me how to get the path or let the bitmap in gallery as soon as I finish the intent?

MyCodes:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    Date today = new Date();

                    fileName = Integer.toString(today.getYear()) + Integer.toString(today.getMonth()) + Integer.toString(today.getDay()) +
                            Integer.toString(today.getHours()) + Integer.toString(today.getMinutes()) + Integer.toString(today.getSeconds());

                    File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName + ".jpg");
                    tempUri = Uri.fromFile(out);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKEPHOTO);
                    break;
```

And in onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == COMPLETE)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if (uri != null)
            {
                    uris[currentIndex] = uri;
                    setBitmapFromUri();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == TAKEPHOTO)
    {
        uris[currentIndex] = tempUri;
        setBitmapFromUri();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here is the setBitmapFromUri:

```
private void setBitmapFromUri()
{
    Uri uri = uris[currentIndex];

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    try
    {
        String path = getAbsoluteImagePath(uri);

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);

        int tag = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

        int degree = 0;
        if (tag == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
        {
            degree = 90;
        }
        else if (tag == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
        {
            degree = 180;
        }
        else if (tag == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
        {
            degree = 270;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale (2 * getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 3 / bitmap.getWidth(), 2 * getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 3 / bitmap.getHeight());
        matrix.setRotate(degree);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        imageViews.get(currentIndex).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


}
```

Here is the exception:

```
05-18 10:38:20.645: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.Trine.HideAndSeek/com.Trine.HideAndSeek.UploadHints}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2653)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2695)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Trine.HideAndSeek.UploadHints.getAbsoluteImagePath(UploadHints.java:324)
    at com.Trine.HideAndSeek.UploadHints.setBitmapFromUri(UploadHints.java:140)
    at com.Trine.HideAndSeek.UploadHints.onActivityResult(UploadHints.java:196)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2649)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this for getting real file path from Uri of image..

```
//----------------------------------------
/**
 * This method is used to get real path of file from from uri
 * 
 * @param contentUri
 * @return String
 */
//----------------------------------------
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
{
    try
    {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}
```

Also, To view your captured image in Gallery you have to initiate android media Scanner from your application.

Try this line, after captured image..

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: Yes, I have such codes but it can not return the path... But if I restart the machine again. It works! So it really confusing.

Comment: Actually, when you restart your device then Android Media Scanner initiate and it scan the all files available in storage then gallery is displayed those files.

Comment: Thanks, then how to initiate the Android Media Scanner?

Comment: And can you give any reason that may cause my failure in getting the path?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the images from the gallery. Thought still can not get the path.

Comment: String path = getAbsoluteImagePath(uri);
put this line in onActivityResult() in if (uri != null) and check the path.. If its still null then use function mentioned by me..

Comment: Actually , File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName + ".jpg");
is your file path of stored Image. Just go to that location to check its correct or not. If yes then use that, no need to convert from Uri..

Comment: Well it's a good idea, I'm just trapped to the strange problem... But can you tell me why no data comes back? Thx.

Comment: Actually, Its seems to problem on certain device, in which Camera Application return null data. If you have a other device then try on it.

Comment: The same thing happen with my application, I tested on HTC Senstaion 2.3.5 and its returns me null data and my Galaxy Note returns me data with captured image Uri. So I just make a trick using filePath given in EXTRA_OUTPUT params in camera Intent, I check for file existance if it exist then I used that file for Bitmap..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is working for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"temp_file_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

try 
{
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_FOR_IMG_PROCESSING);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
{   
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```